# I can access MsDeploy Agent Service without logging in!

Tags: msdeploy

I've installed MsDeploy Agent Service to a server. With msdeploy.exe i can dump and sync everything without entering any login or password from a client machine. I've deleted all credentials from the controlpanel so i can't be that. Is MsDeploy Agent Service totally security free?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your username and password the same on the server and the client machine? Just because you removed all creds from Control Panel, doesn't mean that your domain creds don't exist (if you're in a domain), or the creds that are actually associated with your current session on the client machine.

Comment: my username and password were same at my dev box and the server.

Comment: also, session credentials disappear first when you log out then in again